# Python instance attribute not being recognized

Tags: python, attributes, instance

I have the following code in python:

```
class state:
      def _init_(self):
            self.x=list([])
            self.possibleChests=list([])
            self.visitedChests=list([])

      def checkKeys(self):
            print self.x

      def addKey(self,x):
            self.x.append(key)


current_state=state()
future_state=state()

current_state.addKey(4)
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: state instance has no attribute 'x'
```

Why is 'x' not being recognized as an instance attribute?

Comment: It's `__init__`, not `_init_`

Comment: `list([])` is *completely* pointless. You can use `[]` or (if you must) `list()`.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken wouldn't `def addKey(self,x):` also need to be changed to `def addKey(self, key):` since it never actually passes the value to append?

Comment: Yes, Bob you are right. I fixed that one too. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need double underscores around `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self):
```

Otherwise, Python will treat the function as just a normal method and not the [`__init__` special method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__).